# create Instance holding multiple Instances

Tags: java, generics

In java how can i create a class holding multiple records or values of any type to its instance ?

For example, `MyDataset<AnyType>`, will be holding multiple values of type `AnyType`.

How should I create `MyDataset` class, so that when I create an instance of `MyDataset`, I could add `records or values` to it of one type a time ?

So that later I could iterate `MyDataset<AnyType>` to get values.

Comment: Your question looks to be a specific example of the more broad question, "how do I use generics in Java?"

Comment: Why not using `List<Anytype>`?

Comment: @Andronicus, List will be there I guess wrapped by the main Dataset class I guess. What's a efficient way ?

Comment: Make the class generic `public class MyClass<T>` and include a generic `List<T>` within it. Then when creating instances, declare with the concrete type. This should all be well explained in most any introduction to generic use in Java tutorial.

Comment: Also, if you want your class to be iterable, then also declare it to `implement Iterable<T>` and return your list's iterator in the `iterator()` method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Curious to know, Its fine doing it your way, but what if I want to store multiple records in a list and every record is having multiple values in it and every value should have one header name assigned to it ? For example RDMS How its gonna look like, any code reference